# Dynamically add elements to object literal

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically create an object literal dynamically. So I start with an empty object:

```
   var myobj = {}
```

and then add entries to it so it ends up looking like so:

```
var myobj = {
    row1 = {
        thing1 : 'thing',
        thing2 : 'thing'
    },
   row2 = {
        thing1 : 'thing',
        thing2 : 'thing'
    }
}
```

I've been trying to do:

```
for(var i = 0; i<rows.length; ++i) {
    myobj.row[count].thing1 = 'thing';
    myobj.row[count].thing2 = 'thing'
}
```

But this does not seem to work. I get a cannot set property of undefined error.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Your markup of how it looks is wrong, that would error. the `=` inside should be `:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give `myobj.row` a value (and one that can accept properties, such as an array or an object) before you can give `myobj.row[count]` a value (and `myobj.row[count]` has to have a value before `myobj.row[count].thing1` or `myobj.row[count].thing2` can be assigned).

```
var myobj = { row: [] };
for(var i = 0; i<rows.length; ++i) {
    var count = i;
    myobj.row[count] = {};
    myobj.row[count].thing1 = 'thing';
    myobj.row[count].thing2 = 'thing';
}
```

Also, if you want to create a property called `row1` then you have to use `["row" + 1]` not `.row.1`)

```
var myobj = {};
for(var i = 0; i<rows.length; ++i) {
    var count = i;
    myobj['row' + count] = {};
    myobj['row' + count].thing1 = 'thing';
    myobj['row' + count].thing2 = 'thing';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treaying row as an array, when it is strings. To use a dynamic string, you need to put the string "row" inside the brackets.

```
myobj.row[count].thing1 = 'thing';
myobj.row[count].thing2 = 'thing'
```

should be

```
myobj["row" + count].thing1 = 'thing';
myobj["row" + count].thing2 = 'thing'
```

but if you are treating it as an "array". Why don't you use an array?

```
var myobj = {
    rows : [ 
        {
            thing1 : 'thing',
            thing2 : 'thing'
        },
        {
            thing1 : 'thing',
            thing2 : 'thing'
        }
    ]
}
```

and than what you did would have worked.

```
myobj.rows[count].thing1 = 'thing';
myobj.rows[count].thing2 = 'thing
```

Answer (score 0):

"row" is not an array, it is an object (because you have {} around it)

You should use:

```
myobj.row1.thing1 = 'thing'
```

If you want to use arrays, they your object should be:

```
var myobj = {
row : [{
        thing1 : 'thing',
        thing2 : 'thing'
    },
   {
        thing1 : 'thing',
        thing2 : 'thing'
    }]
}
```

Hope it helps.